# In IntelliJ 2016.2 Ultimate edition, how to add JPA facet when we don't use a persistence.xml?

Tags: intellij-idea

My Project doesnot have a persistence.xml.
I use annotations in my spring-boot based application.
How can I add the JPA facet ?
When I try to add a jpa facet, it enforces me to select persistence.xml, and if it is not present, it is trying to create one, which I don't want.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This used to work okay in IntelliJ 15

Answer (score 0):

For now I got this working with a near-empty **persistence.xml** in the **META-INF** folder of my project.
After this it works fine, but I would love this to work without this persistence.xml as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <!– Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files –>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If anybody knows any other solution please comment.
else if this works for you, you can rate this answer up :-)